# how to call php function from submit button?

Tags: php

my filename is contacts.php that have two submit buttons;i want that if insert button is pressed insert function is called and if select is pressed select is called.i have written following code:

```
//contacts.php
<?php
 if(isset($_REQUEST['select']))
{
    select();
}
else
{
    insert();
}
?>

<html>
<body>
<form action="contacts.php">
<input type="text" name="txt"/>
<input type="submit" name="insert" value="insert" />
<input type="submit" name="select" value="select"/>
</form>

<?php
function select()
{
   //do something
}
function insert()
{
   //do something
}
?>
```

but it is not working .please help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['insert'])) {
    insert();
} elseif (isset($_REQUEST['select'])) {
    select();
}
```

Your code is calling `insert()` even if no button is clicked, which will happen when the page is first displayed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `return` inside function to return the result , you have to use echo to print the result while calling function.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['select']))
{
    echo select();
}
elseif(isset($_REQUEST['insert']))
{
    echo insert();
}
```

Comment: That's a pretty significant _if_.

Comment: @Barmar You forgot `)` in first `if` and `()` in elseif. :)

Comment: @Barmar See another same question from same user http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873067/unable-to-make-mysql-connection-on-data-post

Answer (score 1):

use post method because it is secure

```
//contacts.php
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['select']))
{
    select();
}
else
{
    insert();
}
?>

<html>
<body>
<form action="contacts.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="txt"/>
<input type="submit" name="insert" value="insert" />
<input type="submit" name="select" value="select"/>
</form>

<?php
function select()
{
   //do something
}
function insert()
{
   //do something
}
?>
```

Comment: 'post' is no more  secure than 'get'

Comment: And even if it is, it shouldn't affect whether the script runs correctly.

Comment: @Dagon , why it would be?

Comment: It may be a reasononable suggestion, but it won't fix the problem. It should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: he can solve this problem with use of my answer, that is nothing wrong

Answer (score 1):

As has been described by several people (summarizing the previous comments), you have two options.

The first is to send the data via POST or GET to the server directly and reserve (refresh) the page based on whatever you do inside select() and insert().

While this is not the right place for a POST v GET discussion, convention is to use POST when sending data to the server. POST is slightly more secure because the information is not stored in the browser. Read more about the two here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

The second option is to use AJAX to accomplish your task without refreshing the web page. In short, AJAX uses Javascript methods that you place on your page to communicate with your server, thus avoiding the need for the PHP on the server to actually change anything on the page (which would require a refresh). A code example of AJAX can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first

Comment: He's using GET, since that's the default. And `$_REQUEST` combines the contents of `$_GET` and `$_POST`, so it doesn't matter which method he uses. How is this an "answer"?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$insert = $_POST['insert'];
$select = $_POST['select'];

if ($insert) {
insert();
}

if ($select) {
select();
}

else {
echo 'press any button...';
}
?>

<html>
<body>
<form action="contacts.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="txt"/>
<input type="submit" name="insert" value="insert" />
<input type="submit" name="select" value="select"/>
</form>

<?php
function select() {
echo 'you pressed the [select] button';
exit;
}

function insert() {
echo 'you pressed the [insert] button';
exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Quite rightly it has already been pointed out, that you are using reserved words as a function name. Simply rename your functions to something like button_insert(), button_select() or whatever