# unable to make mysql connection on data post

Tags: php, mysql

my filename is contacts.php;i want that if select button is pressed select function is called.but it is showing error.i have written following code:

```
           //contacts.php
    <?php
    //1.CREATE CONNECTION
    $connection=mysql_connect("localhost","root","human");
    if(!$connection)
    {
    die("DataBase Connection Failed: ".mysql_error());
    }

    //2.SELECT DATABASE
    $db_select=mysql_select_db("vikas",$connection);
    if(!$db_select)
    {
    die("DataBase Selection Failed: ".mysql_error());
    }

    if(isset($_REQUEST['select']))
    {
    select();
    }

    //select function
    function select()
    {
    echo '<div id="show" style="background-color:#DDDDDD;">';
    $result=mysql_query("select * from contacts", $connection);
    if(!$result)
    {
    die("DataBase Query Failed: ".mysql_error());
    }
    echo <<<END
    <table name=contact>
    <tr><th>ID</th>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>NUMBER</th></tr>
    END;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo '<tr><td>'.$row["number"].'</td><td>'.$row["name"].'</td></tr>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
    }
    //end of select
    ?>

    <html>
    <body> 
    <form action="contacts.php">
    ENTER ID:<br>
    <input type="text" name="id"/><br>
    ENTER NAME(20 chars):<br>
    <input type="text" name="name"/><br>
    ENTER NUMBER(10 digits):<br>
    <input type="text" name="number"/><br>
    <input type="submit" name="select" value="select"/>
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

but it is showing error undefined var connection .please help
this is the error "Undefined variable: connection in C:\wamp\www\site2sms-call\contacts.php"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `$connection` in not within `select` function scope. Pass it via function parameter.

```
function select($connection)
{
echo '<div id="show" style="background-color:#DDDDDD;">';
$result=mysql_query("select * from contacts", $connection);
```

While calling select function

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['select']))
{
    select($connection);
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to pass the $connection parameter in mysql_query ? Is it required ?

Comment: @VivekSadh No, its optional. But if OP wants to pass it, it is unavailable in that function scope, hence use function parameter to pass it to that function. :)

Comment: it is unavailable in that function, ??

Comment: @VivekSadh unavailable in function scope. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you get the message inside your select-function? Inside functions variables have an own scope, see here http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php
This means inside your function PHP don't knows your "outside" variable $connection. You have to pass it to the function

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    //1.CREATE CONNECTION
    $connection=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if(!$connection)
    {
    die("DataBase Connection Failed: ".mysql_error());
    }

    //2.SELECT DATABASE
    $db_select=mysql_select_db("test",$connection);
    if(!$db_select)
    {
    die("DataBase Selection Failed: ".mysql_error());
    }

    if(isset($_REQUEST['select']))
    {
    select();
    }

    //select function
    function select()
    { ?>
    <div id="show" style="background-color:#DDDDDD;">
    <?php 
    $result=mysql_query("select * from contacts", $connection);
    if(!$result)
    {
    die("DataBase Query Failed: ".mysql_error());
    } ?>

   <table name=contact>
    <tr><th>ID</th>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>NUMBER</th></tr>
   <?php
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    { ?>
       <tr><td><?php echo $row["number"];?>
       </td><td><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></td></tr>
   <?php  } ?>
    </div>
  <?php  }
    //end of select
    ?>
    <html>
    <body> 
    <form action="contacts.php">
    ENTER ID:<br>
    <input type="text" name="id"/><br>
    ENTER NAME(20 chars):<br>
    <input type="text" name="name"/><br>
    ENTER NUMBER(10 digits):<br>
    <input type="text" name="number"/><br>
    <input type="submit" name="select" value="select"/>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: When posting an answer, it's always best to actually explain what exactly that you did.